# How creating keyboard shortcuts for MS Office Quick Access Toolbar?

Tags: microsoft-office

I added Speak command to the Quick Access Toolbar, so that there are now four commands, Save, Undo, Redo and Speak.

And I find myself using the Speak command more than anything else, and it does not have a pre defined keyboard shortcut my MS.

Is there a way to create a custom shortcut for it?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have it in your ribbon you can reach it pressing ALT + it's sequence number on the ribbon. (ALT+4 in your example as that's the 4th option).

Pressing and holding ALT also shows you the available shortcut options.